# how to check touch on a particular bitmap among multiple bitmaps drawn on a same canvas in android?

Tags: canvas, bitmap

I need a help to check onTouch event on a particular bitmap among multiple bitmaps drawn onto same canvas...
I can move that bitmap among all but problem is that it is moving on touch of whole canvas while it should move only on touch of that bitmaps area...

```
  canvas.drawBitmap(MainActivity.bmp, MainActivity.bPX[i], MainActivity.bPY[i], null);
  canvas.drawBitmap(MainActivity.bmp1, MainActivity.bPX[i], MainActivity.bPY[i], null);
```

here in my code the if condition in place of bmp.getDensity() i have used bmp.getWidth() but in case of that my condition never become true...

```
                if(mLastTouchX >= mPX[i] && mLastTouchX < (mPX[i]+bmp.getDensity()) 
                        && mLastTouchY >= mPY[i] && mLastTouchY < (mPY[i]+bmp.getDensity())
```

So what should i use here so that my condition becomes true...

Comment: Hey Is there any one here who can solve my issue???